# gitlab-ctl reconfigure: Unable to determine node name

Tags: chef-infra, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I did setup a new GitLab instance on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS. Installing the package went fine and GitLab seems to be up and running. I then started to configure the instance and setup SMTP in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`. Afterwards I ran `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`. It failed with the following error message:

```
Starting Chef Client, version 13.6.4

Running handlers:
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

Unable to determine node name: configure node_name or configure the system's hostname and fqdn

Running handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 10 seconds
```

The system's hostname and fqdn are set:

```
$ hostname --fqdn
git-lab.dom
$ hostname
git-lab
```

Ohai seems to to successfully read hostname, fqdn and domain:

```
$ /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ohai
[...]
"hostname": "git-lab",
"machinename": "git-lab",
"fqdn": "git-lab.dom",
"domain": "dom",
[...]
```

The [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36785430) suggested to manually set the `node_name` in `/etc/chef/client.rb`. However, the gitlab omnibus package seems to put the client.rb somewhere else. I am also reluctant to follow this advice since it seems strange to me that I did not have to do it for other GitLab installations so far. Also the docs state (emphasis mine):

> node_name: The name of the node. Determines which configuration should
>   be applied and sets the client_name, which is the name used when
>   authenticating to a Chef server. The default value is the FQDN of the
>   chef-client, as detected by Ohai. In general, **Chef recommends that you
>   leave this setting blank** and let Ohai assign the FQDN of the node as
>   the node_name during each chef-client run.

How can I solve the issue and continue configuring my new installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by insufficient memory. After giving the virtual machine more memory the error went away.

Comment: The GItLab documentation (in 2021) specifies 4GB as the minimum requirement, but  recommends 2GB of swap. I find that my VMs require 6GB (without the swap). https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/requirements.html#memory

Answer (score 5):

Restarting the machine has resolved this issue for me.

Comment: This works for sure. Wanted to run gitlab on a low spec.